# Sending Session in play framework template with java

Tags: java, templates, session, playframework, playframework-2.3

How I am trying from controller:

```
 public static Result index() {
    session("connected", "user@gmail.com");
    System.out.println(session("connected"));
    return ok(views.html.index.render("testing"));
 }
```

And now I am trying to get session in html,
how I am trying in views `index.scala.html`

```
@(message: String)(implicit session:play.api.mvc.Session)
@main(message) {
<div class="wrapper">
...
```

And I am getting:

```
error: method render in class index cannot be applied to given types;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare the implicit session parameter within your template when working with Java. Just use `@session.get("connected")` within your template to retrieve the respective value from the session.

Comment: yeah now its work, but my eclipse is giving error for using it directly

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've given up eclipse for Play development a while ago because of various issues I had with it. I tested this with IDEA without any problems.

Comment: what if I need to pass in `implicit cache`? as in the object `play.api.mvc.CacheApi`

Comment: @Zennichimaro For Play 2.6, have a look at [injectable templates](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Highlights26#injectable-twirl-templates). I've created a [Java based gist](https://gist.github.com/edgarmueller/cef297f778db73a5887f1a01fae7ec80), which illustrates their usage.